# ZXingObjC Scanning Small 2D Matrix Codes on Physical Products

Tags: ios

ZXingObjC library works great but when scanning very small 2d Matrix codes on physical products the iPhone camera becomes blurry since could not scan those codes. How does one scan the little code shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Which iOS device are you using? For such a small barcode you need one with a really good camera and autofocus.

Comment: I am using iPhone 5 with iOS 7. Even with the built in Camera app I cannot really focus on those small codes. I guess there are different devices meant to scan those little suckers.

Comment: Good lighting might help.

Comment: The only way the barcode is clear is then using zooming capabilities of the iPhone 5. I believe the solution is to implement zooming (pinch to zoom).